# Removing last image via jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I would like to add an image at the end of each "booklist" within the "genre" div, but remove it for the last "booklist" within each genre. The following code is it adding just fine, but I'm messing something up when it comes to the removal. It's only removing the last image from the last .booklist on the page.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="genre">

    <div class="booklist">
    <!-- stuff -->
    </div><!-- .booklist -->

    <div class="booklist">
    <!-- stuff -->
    </div><!-- .booklist -->

</div><!-- .genre -->

<div class="genre">

    <div class="booklist">
    <!-- stuff -->
    </div><!-- .booklist -->

    <div class="booklist">
    <!-- stuff -->
    </div><!-- .booklist -->

 </div><!-- .genre -->
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
// ADD HEART DIVIDER BETWEEN SERIES ON BOOK PAGE
$(".genre .booklist").append("<img class='hr' src='"+my_home_object.my_stylesheet_path+"/images/heart-hr.png' />");
$(".genre .booklist:last img:last").remove();
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to remove the last imgs in the last divs with class `"booklist"` in each `"genre"`:

```
$(".genre .booklist:last-child > img:last-child").remove();
```

[`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) only selects one element, so use [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/).

Comment: That removes all the images in the last .booklist div, though - I only want to remove the last image within the last .booklist div within each .genre block. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that's still removing all images in the last .booklist div for each genre. Check it out here: http://216.172.167.18/~julia/books/ - "The Secrets of Hadley Green" should have one book cover image, for instance, and "Thrillseekers Anonymous" should have 3 cover images.

Comment: @Michelle See new edit - I added a child selector, based on your html.

Comment: Oh HUZZAH! You are so good - thank you!!! Worked perfectly. I thought I had tried every possible combo but I obviously missed that one. :)

Comment: @Michelle On another note: you could just append to everything but the last child: `$(".genre .booklist:not(:last-child)").append...`